# Grant access only to System databases

Tags: sql-server, permissions

Is it possible give an SA like permission minus any access to user databases?  I want people to be able to collect information about Sql Server from the system databases but I want to make sure the User databases cannot be touched.  What is the best way to approach that?

Comment: Can you be more specific about version? And *exactly* what "information about SQL Server" you want them to see?

Comment: Alright so, I want to be able to do anything on the server, not including ANYTHING to do with user databases. I know that is wide open but that's the gist of it.  The main idea is to just protect the user databases from changes but leave it open to do just about anything else.

Comment: So you want a car that does anything on highways but can't drive on one-way surface streets. Got it. That should narrow it down for sure. :-) Seriously, if you have such generic requirements, you're going to get generic answers. If you can be more specific, I think you'll get better help.

Comment: I think your question will be greatly improved by being very specific. Since this is a security related topic, I feel it'd be poor form for us to assume we understand precisely what "anything to a user database" means in your mind.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of approaches you can take.  The better one is to grant `VIEW SERVER STATE`.  This gives you access to the DMOs that give you information about the server.

The other version (which I don't recommend) is to grant `CONTROL SERVER`.  This permission is very similar to SYSADMIN but you can do DENYs.  So you could `DENY CONNECT` on each of the user databases.  The down side here is that you are giving someone (for example) the ability to stop & start the SQL Services.

Unless you have a **VERY** good reason to go beyond `VIEW SERVER STATE` just go with that one.

You can also look at the list of [server level roles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188659.aspx) and see what matches your needs.  Just remember that someone with `securityadmin` for example could create a login with sufficient permissions to affect the databases.

Comment: Suppose you want to be able to have the ID allows some changes (once again, not to user databases)  I want to leave the possibility of the ID to auto remediation issues in the future, maybe rerun a failed job, changes account passwords across the board, shoot out an email under certain conditions etc

Comment: @Someguy You need to be specific about what you want them to be able to do and what you don't want them to be able to do. If you just don't want them to be able to select data, you can look at `DENY SELECT ALL USER SECURABLES` - but I have no idea if that's what you really want (or if you're on a version that supports it). Currently you're saying "I kind of want a car that goes over 60, has bucket seats, and plenty of room in the trunk." You're not going to get a very good car recommendation based on those requirements.

Comment: Use View Server State, Security Admin and AgentOperator (in MSDB).  Fair warning though Security Admin has a LOT of power (the ability to change passwords & permissions)

Comment: Alright so, I want to be able to do anything on the server, not including ANYTHING to do with user databases.  I know that is wide open but that's the gist of it.

Comment: Anything is REALLY broad.  It includes things like stopping SQL Server.